# Call Webservice from HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

How we can call webservice from html page using javascript

Comment: You use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Specifically, the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object in JS.

Comment: What kind of web service? What do you want to do with the results? Please be more specific. You can edit your question.

Comment: Upvoted to support (and to not to be rude for "newbies" to SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName", 
    data: "{}", 
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Because of **same origin restrictions**, you might need to use JSONP through script injection.
2. Of course if you are talking a Web Service on the **same origin**, just use AJAX.
3. Through an web browser extension

Comment: IMO this is the most appropriate answer for *web services*.  Here's more info on utilizing JSONP with jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON and here's more info on JSONP itself: http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/